# How to calculate probability that a draw from a standard normal distribution is greater than a draw from a uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am self-studying some probability for fun... I realised I have no idea how I would calculate P[X>Y] if X~N(0,1) and Y~U(0,1). Running simulations suggests the answer should be around 0.315, but I am looking for an integral form to compute the exact value.

I have tried $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dxdy$$ but this doesn't seem to be giving me the correct values.

Comment: $$P(X>Y) = \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp( (x-y)^2/2))\,dx\,dy$$ One way to think about it is that conditional on $Y$, $X-Y$ is a gaussian centered at $Y$. Hence the inner integral. Then you average the conditional probability $P(X>Y | Y)$ over all realizations of $Y$ to get the unconditional probability $P(X>Y)$. In formulae, $$P(X>Y) = E[P(X>Y \mid Y)] = E \left\{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp((x-Y)^2/2)\,dx \right\}$$

Comment: Amazing, thankyou! So intuitive.

Comment: Your title "probability that a draw from a uniform distribution is greater than a draw from a standard normal distribution" is the reverse of your text "P[X>Y] if X~N(0,1) and Y~U(0,1)".  Note the difference in means between the two distributions.

Comment: I suspect your $0.315$ result could be closer to $0.3156268098$

Comment: Thankyou Henry, I've updated the title to reflect this.